# Uncaught TypeError: arr.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm a JS beginner, and stumbled upon a problem I cannot figure out. The title error comes up after I run this simple sum function in Sublime:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS Exercise</title>
    <script src="JSexercise.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JS Exercise</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function sumArray(arr){
    var sum = 0;
    arr.forEach(function(element){
        sum+=element;
    });
    return sum;
}

var input = prompt("Give array");
console.log(sumArray(input));
```

Error

> Uncaught TypeError: arr.forEach is not a function     at sumArray
>   (JSexercise.js:3)     at JSexercise.js:10

Comment: `input` is a string it doesn't have `forEach` method, thus the error is expected.

Comment: Why is `input` a string if i specifically prompt it as an `array` ?

Comment: See [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), _result is a string containing the text entered by the user, or null._

Comment: Thank you, that was useful, next time I'll try to read more docs before i ask a question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input variable will take a string. split() is used to convert a string to an array. So first split the string based on the delimiter you pass in prompt which will output an array. Then pass this array to function sumArray.

```
var input= "1 2 3 4 5"; // Enter 1 2 3 4 5 in prompt box
// Split the string by whitespaces - arr will now contain [1,2,3,4,5]
var arr = input.split(" ");
console.log(sumArray(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

the `forFeach` API needs an `array`. `input` is a `string` not an `array`.

```
function sumArray(arr){
    var sum = 0;
    arr.forEach(function(element){
        sum+=element;
    });
    return sum;
}

var responses = [];
var input = prompt("Give array");
responses.push(input)
console.log(sumArray(responses));
```